# Does Neura recognize the locations like Home, Office automatically or I the user has to enter them manually?

Tags: android, api, sdk, geolocation, neura

if my permissions are ...
[
"physicalActivity",
"presenceAtWork"
]

then do I need to have a location registered as "work" in order to have the app automatically trigger the physical activity events like "startedWalking"?

Answer (score 2):

So basically Neura pulls out the sensor data from your user's phone and runs some machine learning algorithm on it. Neura tries to understand the semantic meaning of a location for your user for e.g. whether the place is your user's home/ office / gym.

**Answering your question,**

Neura can understand automatically the location for your user viz. Home, office, grocery store etc, but it might take up to 4-5 days for it to understand.
If you need the results immediately, you can have the user enter his desired location details for e.g. 122 Smith Street is "Home", 7 Bond Street is "Office".
Once Neura understands that a particular event has occurred, it will send you the details of that event via an api call in JSON format. You can also receive the event via a webhook.

You can find more details here: [Neura Events](https://dev.theneura.com/docs/api/events)